# VBA - Unexpected row insert

Tags: vba, excel

**OBJECTIVE**

Copy a group of rows from multiple worksheets and insert into a `CONSOLIDATED` worksheet.

**APPROACH**

1. Go to `CONSOLIDATED` worksheet and remove pre-existing information
2. Use an IF statement to find relevant worksheets where we intend to pull data from
3. Copy relevant columns and rows on each worksheet (e.g A6:G(lastrow))
4. Append copied data to `CONSOLIDATED` worksheet **!!!ERROR**

**(ugly) CODE**

```
Sub consolidateConvert()
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Set CONSOLIDATED as the active worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("CONSOLIDATED").Activate


'Clear previous content from active sheet
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:G10000").ClearContents

'Iterate through workbooks, except for CONSOLIDATED, TITLE, and PIVOT worksheets
For Each ws In Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> "CONSOLIDATED" And ws.Name <> "PIVOT" And ws.Name <> "TITLE" _
     And ws.Name <> "APPENDIX - CURRENCY CONVERTER" And ws.Name <> "MACRO" Then

'Find last row of current worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

'Copy current worksheet cells and insert into CONSOLIDATED worksheet
    ws.Range("A6:G" & lastRow).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlUp).Insert shift:=xlDown
  End If
Next ws

Call currencyConvert
Call addHeaders
```

`currencyConvert` is a function that isn't relevant to this particular question. However, I've added `addHeaders` function below:

```
Sub addHeaders()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim headers() As Variant

'Define worksheet and desired headers
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CONSOLIDATED")
headers() = Array("Fiscal Year", "Month", "Fiscal Month", "Month Year", "Unit", "Project", "Local Expense", "Base Expense")

'Insert row for header placement
Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

'Insert headers
With ws
  For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
    .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
  Next i
End With
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

Below is a screenshot of the unexpected output. Rows 2-7 are unexpected and include some random text strings that aren't present anywhere else within the workbook. Strings may be some weird inheritance issue in VBA but not quite sure (hence the question(s) below).

[image: error with weird text strings]

**QUESTIONS**

1. As mentioned before, Rows 2-7 are added unintentionally and are accompanied with some weird strings. Does anyone have any insight on why ~6 rows are being added (when only 1 should be added - see `addHeaders()`)? Additionally, what is the origin of the unintended strings ("CatalogNickname", "EnvironmentKey", etc.)?

Comment: Has nothing to do with `ws.Range("A6:G" & lastRow).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlUp).Insert shift:=xlDown` ??

Comment: @tjb1 - no (I do not think so), that portion is looking at the other sheets, copying relevant cells and columns, and then inserting the cells into the consolidated worksheet.

Comment: I ran your code and did not have any unintended rows added to the CONSOLIDATED worksheet at all. It seemed to work fine. Perhaps you have other UDFs or an add-in or something else at work?

Comment: I am wondering something about this line: `ws.Range("A6:G" & lastRow).Copy`. Does `lastRow` ever return a value of `<6`? When I put `? Range("A6:G1").Address` in the immediate window it returns `$A$1:$G$6`.

Comment: And are there 6 worksheets you are looping through? It may be copying a blank row for each worksheet.

Comment: @Brian - good questions. `lastRow` is always > 6 and there are never any blank rows in the copied data

Comment: @jonplaca So there is always, at least, one row of data to be copied from each worksheet? How many worksheets are being looped?

Comment: @brian - yes, each sheet has at least 1 row of data (an average of ~240 rows per copy procedure). Roughly 14 sheets total

Comment: @Brian - For now, I am just going to deal with this error. Some users have pointed out that they haven't had an issue so perhaps it's a client-side error. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issues derives from use of `Activate`/`ActiveSheet`

you have to abandon this coding habit, that can subtly mislead you, and use *fully qualified range references* to assure you're acting on wanted workbook/worksheet range

here follows a refactoring of your code with such *fully qualified range references* and a "Value to Value" `range` copy instead of a `Copy`/`Insert` to considerably speed things up:

```
Option Explicit

Sub consolidateConvert()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("CONSOLIDATED") '<--| reference "CONSOLIDATED" worksheet
        .UsedRange.ClearContents '<--| clear its content

        'Iterate through workbooks
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "CONSOLIDATED", "PIVOT", "TITLE", "APPENDIX - CURRENCY CONVERTER", "MACRO" ' <--| discard "CONSOLIDATED", "TITLE", "PIVOT", "APPENDIX - CURRENCY CONVERTER" and "MACRO" worksheets
                    ' do nothing
                Case Else
                    'Find last row of current worksheet
                    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row
                    'Copy current worksheet cells and insert into CONSOLIDATED worksheet
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(lastRow - 5, 7).Value = ws.Range("A6:G" & lastRow).Value '<--| just copy values and speed thing up!
            End Select
        Next ws
        addHeaders .Name '<--| call AddHeaders passing reference worksheet name (i.e. "CONSOLIDATED")
    End With

    currencyConvert '<--| if it acts on "CONSOLIDATED" sheet, you may want to "treat" it as 'addHeaders': take it into 'End With' and pass it '.Name' as a parameter 

End Sub

Sub addHeaders(shtName As String)
    Dim headers As Variant

    headers = Array("Fiscal Year", "Month", "Fiscal Month", "Month Year", "Unit", "Project", "Local Expense", "Base Expense") '<--| Define desired headers
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(headers) - LBound(headers) + 1).Value = headers '<--| write headers from cell A1 rightwards
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this is noticeably faster. However, at `.Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)... '<--| just copy values and speed things up!` I get an `Object Defined Error: 1004`. Yet, despite this error, the values are properly pasted (however, the submodule just quits and doesn't proceed onto `addHeaders .Name`. I believe this might be an issue w.r.t `ws.Range("A6:G" & lastRow)..` but always find these errors the most difficult :(

Comment: "1" which shouldn't be the case since all ranges > 1. Note, when the function runs, it pastes all the proper information into CONSOLIDATED, but leaves 1, blank row at the top of the CONSOLIDATED sheet (prior to adding headers). I started to think that perhaps the function was also running on the CONSOLIDATE page in it's final stage, resulting in `lastRow` = `1`, but the `Select Case ws.Name...do nothing` statement should exempt the CONSOLIDATED worksheet from being effected.

Comment: this means that the current `ws` column "E"  has no data, thus resulting in `lastRow = 1`. Check `ws.name` when it errors out and see why that worksheet has no data in column "E"